# What needs to be fixed for my layout to work with Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I have a problem with a website layout. I noticed it isn't right when using Internet Explorer. You can see the live code at https://byra.ca

How it should be:
[image: How it should be]

How it is with IE:
[image: How it is with IE]

The problem is, I have no idea how to fix this. Anyone knows what css I am using that isn't compatible with IE and that is causing the issue?

I was able to test the website using IE9 and IE10. I don't know if the issue is also happening with IE11.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way to fix this is to set an explicit `min-height` property on any of the three problematic `div`s:

`<div class="byra-block to-animate fadeInRight animated" style="background-image: url(/images/design/img_1.jpg); min-height: 500px;">`

If you can come up with an acceptable value for `min-height` for the three block `div`s, both Internet Explorer and other browsers should respect it.

Comment: I realized I already had a min-height attribute, but set to 300px (probably from when the text in those box was just a little Lorem Ipsum). Changed it to 500px and it solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Change `flex: 1` to `flex: 1 0 auto` to the `.byra-text` div.

```css
#byra-intro .byra-block > .byra-text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to solve the issue with this solution.